# How can I say we are going to start developing a new system?

Tags: synonyms

Would you give me advice on how I can say we are　developing a new system?

The context is train accidents, and the system I am mentioning is a signaling system which checks the train speed and applies brakes automatically when the train speed exceeds its speed profile. I was asked to talk about the history of the system at a meeting and am preparing presentation material.

I would like to say:

> We started developing a new system triggered by the accident.

Does this sentence make sense, or can I make the English clearer?

Comment: You don't say what sort of accident.  Let's assume it was an airline accident, even though commercial airlines are the safest mode of transportation in the US, at least.  Then you could say:   The accident triggered a review of our operating systems, with particular emphasis on maintenance and cockpit procedures.  But without knowing what kind of accident you are referring to, we can't answer your Q.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am talking about train accidents, and the system I am mentioning is a signalling system which checks the train speed and applies brake automatically when the train speed exceeds it's speed profile. I was asked to talk about the history of the system at a meeting and am preparing presentation material.  Is am sorry to tell only  insufficient information.

Comment: The accident triggered our development of new signaling and braking systems

Comment: You could also say "in response to the accident" or "as a result of the accident".

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I also appreciate you correcting my English question. I had a lot of knowledge from all advice. Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you trying to say that your system is supposed to prevent future accidents, or that the system was built in response to past accidents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fewer words are better, especially in English which has endless (progressive) tenses.

Why not "a new system is being developed..." or "we are developing a new system..."?

If you must be clearer, "we (already) started developing a new system..."

words like "going to" are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. "I am developing a new system" is better.